# How to assign correct path in codeigniter/php in index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I am exploring PHP, so pardon me if someone finds my question silly.

I have a PHP file called index.php in which i have three variable which are,

```
$system_path = '../../';
$application_folder = '../';
$view_folder = '';
```

I have installed xampp, which is running correctly now i need to run the index.php file, the moment i run php file it throws an error stating 'system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php'. Which is quite self explanatory, path which i gave is incorrect, but i don't know which path to use? I searched here as well OP says you must have system folder and application folder,sadly i can not see that as well and i have not removed or delete anything.

My path where i have php files : C:\xampp\htdocs\admin
[image]

If anyone can guide what will be my system_path, application_folder and view_folder that will be great.

Comment: try to re-install codeigniter, this is not the complete setup! https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/archive/3.1.11.zip. e.g.: cache normally is inside the application folder

Comment: I followed link and downloaded the zip file of codeigniter, now i have to copy my admin folder to system location?

Comment: this admin folder is not from Codeigniter, I suppose? I'd just put my codeigniter project in a folder anywhere on your disk and create an alias to it, then call it with http:\\alias

Comment: Admin folder is a local website in which i have all php files..
What i did is copy extract codeigniter folder in htdocs of xampp, then copied admin folder in system.. now if i run from localhost i can see welcome page of codeigniter, i need to see index.php page of admin folder instead of welcome.php  which is default page for codeigniter.

Comment: the default view file is welcome.php, index.php you never "see"

Comment: Correct i want to display my index.php

Comment: The index.php serves as the front controller, initializing the base resources needed to run CodeIgniter. I'd suggest you read once more through this: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: there is no such thing to assign a path. you can call them directly using the MVC pattern of Codeigniter.